# What does the field bi_sector from struct bio represent

Tags: linux, kernel

There is a field in kernel's `struct bio`: `bi_sector`.

What does it represent? Specifically I want to know if all pages hold in the `bi_io_vec` list bound to the same sector on disk.

Answer (score 2):

it represents the first sector of  bio's I/O operation